# How to add the 2 user control in web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I am using User Controls in my webforms

when I am adding 2nd user controls it's not working

```
   <%@ Register src="~/Pages/UserControls/ProjectDetails.ascx" TagName="ProjectDetails" TagPrefix="ucPrjDetails" %>

<%@ Register src="~/Pages/UserControls/UCBSiteDetails.ascx" TagName="SiteDetails" TagPrefix="ucPrjDetails" %>
```

[image: SiteDetails]

when I tried to add in web.config also it's not allowing

Answer (score 1):

things you can try that helped me out in the past:

- Clean build
- Delete the page and recreate it, then add the user
  controls again
- Make use of intellisense in source code mode of the
  page, don't use drag and drop to put the user controls